# innodb_redo0 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size

Tags: mysql, innodb

My Ubuntu 22.04 server is suddenly telling me that "The redo log file "./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0 size 23289856 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size."  My innodb_page_size is 16K, so the error is correct, but I can't seem to find any advice on how to fix it.  I tried moving ib_redo0 out of the way but that didn't help.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you make any changes to the config file?  (I do not happen to know where the redo-file size comes from.)

Comment: Same problem with MySQL 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 on Ubuntu 20.04 container (Proxmox). Needed to restore a backup of the container from 28.07. The update brakes it once more. Will try to investigate more later.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this issue. It appeared to be specific to using ZFS on Ubuntu, in my case it was during an upgrade to MYSQL 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2.

Following details in [this Ubuntu issue report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-8.0/+bug/1969247) and [this MySQL issue report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108012) I was able to come up with a solution that worked in my environment.

There are 3 commands below to be ran as root or with `sudo`. You should replace `8192` in the first with the result of `<broken_file_size> % <default_page_size>`. The default page size is usually `16384` unless modified.
You may need to replace the `#ib_redo0` part of the second command with the broken file reported in the error message.
These commands are intended to pad out the reportedly invalid file with zeros.

***Perform a backup before running!***

```bash
# Gather required zeros to append
# Will create a "zeros" file in the current directory
# This has been calculated based upon 23289856 % 16384 = 8192 or <broken_file_size> % <default_page_size>
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=8192 of=./zeros

# Append zeroes to invalid file
cat zeros >> /var/lib/mysql/#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0

# Restart MySQL
systemctl restart mysql.service
```

I'd be wary of remaining on ZFS, even if the above fixes things, for the sake of potentially hitting the same issue again.

Comment: Yep. Ubuntu on ZFS update of MYSQL to MYSQL 8.0.30 caused the problem. The solution worked for me as well. Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem in a LXD Container running on ZFS. I had to move it to a different type of storage-pool, e.g. Directory or BTRFS.

After that the solution of @DanBrown worked for me too.

Thank you.